# How to properly group objects with stacklayout

Tags: qt, qml

I'm trying to get a tab bar to switch position from a repeater to another item.

Currently I have this:

```
TabBar {
    id: bar
    width: parent.width
    TabButton {
        text: qsTr("History")
    }
    TabButton {
        text: qsTr("Details")
    }

}
StackLayout {
    id: stack
    width: parent.width
    currentIndex: bar.currentIndex

    Repeater {
        id: repeat
        model: attributes

        Row {
            id: detailsTab
            Layout.fillWidth: true
            clip: true
            spacing: 5 * scaleFactor

            Text {
                Layout.preferredWidth: popupColumn.width * 0.55
                Layout.fillHeight: true
                text:  attributeName
                wrapMode: Text.WrapAnywhere
                font.pixelSize: 12 * scaleFactor
                color: "#FFFCF7"
            }

            Text {
                Layout.fillWidth: true
                Layout.fillHeight: true
                text:attributeValue
                wrapMode: Text.WrapAnywhere
                font.pixelSize: 12 * scaleFactor
                color: "#FFFCF7"

            }
        }
    }

    Item {
        id: discoverTab
    }
}
```

When the tab button history is clicked i expect the entire repeater to be displayed. Instead what happens is one field from the text object is displayed and when I click details tab the next text from the repeater is displayed.

How do I group properly to get the functionallity I want?

Comment: Please provide [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Now your code is incomplete and couldn't be run.

Comment: Wrap the `Repeater` in an `Item`